# React: Let child class assign state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

## Design explained

I have a `React` class with an arrow function that gets called from within child classes (modules). It's simply called `saveData` and its purpose is to save an input value specific to each module to be saved to `state`. So well, my default state has default props (`static defaultProps`):

```
state = {
  a : this.props.initialA,
  b : this.props.initialB,
  c : ...
}
```

And said `saveData` function is a fat arrow function that's supposed to push the input value from the child class to a specific state property in the parent:

```
saveData = (val) => this.setState( {a : val} )
```

Each child class gets the `saveData` function passed with JSX and has its own input. When a button is clicked I call the function with the value as parameter:

```
/* A child class */

pushData = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  const val = this.refs.a.value
  this.props.saveData(val)
}

render() {
  return(
    <input id='a' ref='a' ... />
    <button onClick={this.pushData} ... />
  )
}
```

### This is all fine! Now for my concern

As you can see the state property `a` is hard coded in the above examples. This is ***not*** what I want. I would want to have another parameter set the state property which in my head could be as simple as:

```
/* In parent class */

saveData = (prop, val) => this.setState( {prop : val} )


/* In child class */

pushData = (e) => {
  ...
  const val  = this.refs.a.value,
        prop = a;
  this.props.saveData(prop, val)
}
```

---

Now here are the problems I face with this approach:

- Did I understand right that arrow functions don't accept parameters? Because I totally do use `(e)` in `pushData` and even `(val)` in `saveData` has worked for me before.
- **The crucial point:** Whatever way I put it, the property in `this.setState({prop:val})` won't get assigned. It will just add a new property called `prop` even if `prop` is a variable, a parameter, or a rest parameter with a totally different content.

### Is there a way to have `...setState({prop...` be assigned by the child class?

*(Or am I just being overly complicated? Am I not thinking `React`? I sometimes feel like thinking in React is like thinking `$con"!"\˜*.ht"&&su20%+o?else{((())...())}of`)*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a variable for a key in a JavaScript object literal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/using-a-variable-for-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-literal)

Comment: @FelixKling I would want to mark this accordingly, yet I feel like the question is definetly not a duplicate. People might find this problem of mine looking for ReactJS and the setState function cause they don't even know what they're doing wrong (like me). Apparently the solution is mentioned there, just like it is here. Is the same solution to a different question still a duplicate? Please clarify and I'll mark accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrow functions are nothing but syntactic sugar for

```
()=>{} is equivalent to function(){}.bind(this)
```

So, they behave exactly similar to any other function, except that the scope is lexically bound. It does take params. If saveData is not working in the way you want it to, you are probably invoking the function with wrong values.

And,when you do this

```
saveData = (prop, val) => this.setState( {prop:val} )
```

javascript does not evaluate `prop` as a variable. Here 'prop' is interpreted as a string.

Instead, try this in ES5

```
var temp = {};
temp[prop] = val;
saveData = (prop, val) => this.setState( temp )
```

or this, in ES6,

```
saveData = (prop, val) => this.setState({[prop]:val})
```

[] allows you to evaluate a variable enclosed within it.

Comment: You sir, released my headache I've had for hours within a few minutes...Thank you very much! Would you mind explaining a bit futher why JavaScript won't interpret `prop` but `val` and why I have to enclose the `prop` param in square brackets? Not something I'd normally do, but this was the whole solution to this.

Comment: That's how Javascript should work right? If you want to do {title:'Sometititle'}, interpreting 'title' as a variable doesn't make sense, it is intended to be a string. However, there are cases where you need to create dynamic props and, which is why, our forefathers have blessed us with '[ ]' in Javascript. Glad I could help Marian.

Comment: Makes me feel like I started with JS yesterday hahaha...Thank you for the explanation!